# insert images in bclogo or other infobox packages

Tags: box, bclogo

I would like to make an `infobox` that includes images. For the `bclogo` package I like the general appearance the most, but I can not find an option about inserting images other than inserting the own images as a logo or the border of the box. Is there a way to insert a graphic with that package?

Otherwise, is there a package, I can make nice infoboxes with, that allows for including images?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage[tikz]{bclogo}

\begin{document}

\begin{bclogo}[couleur=yellow!20, epBord=2, arrondi=0.2, logo=\bcinfo,marge=8, ombre=true, blur, couleurBord=yellow!60, barre=snake, tailleOndu=3]{Liver} The liver is the biggest gland of the human body
\end{bclogo}

\end{document}
```

That would be my examples
it makes an infobox but without the image[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Dealing with boxes, you could try the `tcolorbox`package which offers lots of possibilities to realize what you are looking for.

Comment: nice thanks! I tried the tcolorbox as well before, but didn't succeed inserting an image... now it works, so I will just switch tcolor :)

Comment: Where exactly do you want to insert an image? Can you make a sketch how the result should look like? `\begin{bclogo}{Liver} 
The liver is the biggest gland of the human body

\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image}
\end{bclogo}` seems to work just fine, if this is what you are looking for.

Comment: hey, thanks for the answer. it works now with both, bclogo and tcolor... my mistake was to open a begin{figure} environment inside the box. instead now I just do include graphics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Images work without any problem in `bclogo` boxes:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage[tikz]{bclogo}

\begin{document}

\begin{bclogo}[couleur=yellow!20, epBord=2, arrondi=0.2, logo=\bcinfo,marge=8, ombre=true, blur, couleurBord=yellow!60, barre=snake, tailleOndu=3]{Liver} The liver is the biggest gland of the human body

\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-duck}
\end{bclogo}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course one may not place the image in a floating environment like a `figure`. In case you might want a caption below your image, use the `\captionof` macro from the `caption` package.